# pgfplotstable: Use command when defining new column with create col/assign/.code?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, expansion

Lets say I define the following table `mytable`

```
\pgfplotstableread{
a b
1 100
3 200
5 300
}\mytable
```

I want to create a new colum `label`, that contains `<a> (<b>)`. I want the `b` values to be in a different color. I can make the new column without the coloring either as

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \getthisrow{a}\vala
     \getthisrow{b}\valb
     \edef\newentry{\vala (\valb)}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{label}{\mytable}
```

or

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \edef\newentry{\thisrow{a} (\thisrow{b})}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{label}{\mytable}
```

But if I try to change it to `\edef\newentry{\thisrow{a} \textcolor{blue}{(\thisrow{b})}}` I get the following error:

ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

```
--- TeX said ---
\tikz@deactivatthings ->\def ;
                              {\tikz@nonactivesemicolon }\def :{\tikz@nonact...l.323 ]{label}{\twenty}
```

I quite sure the problem is caused by expanding/escaping issues, but I can't really figure out how to solve them. If the original value in `a` or `b` contains something like `\textcolor{blue}{100}`, I get the same error,  so manually changing the `b` column is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add `\noexpand` to the `\textcolor` command, such as

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \getthisrow{a}\vala
     \getthisrow{b}\valb
     \edef\newentry{\vala \noexpand\textcolor{blue}{(\valb)}}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{label}{\mytable}
```

or

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \edef\newentry{\thisrow{a} \noexpand\textcolor{blue}{(\thisrow{b})}}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{label}{\mytable}
```

---

I am posting this as a QA, as I had a hard time finding the answer (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231994/pgfplotstable-new-column-url)). Hopefully this will save others a few hours.