# pgfplotstable: correct way to generate new columns using custom commands in a table that can be plotted with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfplotstable, fp

Sorry if the title is too big, but I didn't know how to express it as something specific, I try to generate new columns in a table using custom commands, for instance:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\newcoltest}[1]%my custom command
{
\ifthenelse{\isodd{#1}}
{\FPeval{\result}{clip(#1+1)}}
{\FPeval{\result}{clip(#1*3/2-1)}}
\result
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
T
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \getthisrow{T}\vala
     \edef\newentry{\noexpand\newcoltest{\vala}}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{Sa}{\loadedtable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\loadedtable%critic line

\end{document}
```

the critic line is `\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\loadedtable`, which works only with `string type`, when I change to another type or even do not put anything, an error ocurrs.

I put `\noexpand` based on [pgfplotstable: Use command when defining new column with create col/assign/.code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355258/pgfplotstable-use-command-when-defining-new-column-with-create-col-assign-code), since without this I think that my command is not recognized.

I also can't plot it using `tikz`, and I think this is related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\newcoltest}[1]%my custom command
{%
\ifodd#1
\fpeval{trunc(#1+1)}%
\else
\fpeval{trunc(#1*3/2-1)}%
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
T
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \getthisrow{T}\vala
     \edef\newentry{\noexpand\newcoltest{\vala}}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{Sa}{\loadedtable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset\loadedtable%critic line

\end{document}
```

[image]

All I did was to make the stuff expandable by

- going from `fp` to `xfp`, and
- dropping `ifthen` in favor of a simple `\ifodd`.

Comment: yes! @Schrödinger's cat, thanks for your speed and simplicity, in general for these cases, should I avoid using `ifthenelse`?, I have some more complicated commands

Comment: @4lrdyD Avoiding it in general may be a tough call but there are the built in `\ifodd` and `\ifnum` and `\ifcase` tests, which do not not require a package and are expandable. I personally do not use the `ifthen` package, but per se it is a nice package, I think. Happy New Year!

Comment: I understand, I will try to handle that, thanks again and Happy New Year too!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of using `\noexpand` seems good to me, but prevents expansion of:

- the next token;
- only once, i.e.: if your `\newentry` is subject to another `\edef`, the `\noexpand` won't be there anymore to prevent expansion of `\newcoltest`—I guess this must be the cause of your troubles here.

To counter the second point, LaTeX2e's `\protected@edef` and `\protect` mechanism uses a clever trick to make the protection reinstate itself every time it is used inside one of the dedicated macros `\protected@edef`, `\protected@write`, etc. But e-TeX and derived engines (including pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX) have the `\protected` primitive which is more powerful, because it protects macros even inside engine primitives such as `\edef` and `\write`, and doesn't require one to use `\protect`. You just need to declare a macro as `\protected` and voilà, it won't be expanded inside `\edef`, `\write`, etc.

`xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand` macro (as opposed to `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`) creates `\protected` macros, because that is generally the safest thing to do unless you *really* know your macro is expandable. You can very simply use `\NewDocumentCommand` to define `\newcoltest` in order to solve your problem, even keeping `\ifthenelse`, `\FPeval` or other “non-expandable stuff” inside the replacement text of `\newcoltest`. Of course, there is no need for `\noexpand` in this case, since `\NewDocumentCommand` defines engine-protected macros—as if you had used e-TeX's `\protected` primitive.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn % No spurious spaces this way!

\NewDocumentCommand \newcoltest { m }
  {
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{#1}}
      {\FPeval{\result}{clip(#1+1)}}
      {\FPeval{\result}{clip(#1*3/2-1)}}
    \result
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
T
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
     \getthisrow{T}\vala
     \edef\newentry{\newcoltest{\vala}}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\newentry
   }%
]{Sa}{\loadedtable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Besides, since you were talking conditionals with @Schrödinger'scat, you might be interested in knowing that `expl3` has powerful expandable conditionals, for instance `\bool_if:nTF`, `\str_case:nnTF` and all their variants (see [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) after reading [expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf)).

Comment: It may be an interesting option @frougon, but when I change the `string type` to another type as `fixed`, it stops working, I also need to graph it.

Comment: @4lrdyD Right, I wrote this for the MWE, but this can be inappropriate for other uses. AFAIUI, the reason is that with my method, the actual cell contents for the Sa column look like `\newcoltest{1}`, `\newcoltest{2}`, `\newcoltest{3}`, etc., since `\newcoltest` doesn't expand inside `\edef`. It does expand when used in normal document flow, which is why the table can be typeset. But if other code (e.g., graphing) tries to look precisely into the cells, for instance to compute min. and max. values, it won't be able to see more than `\newcoltest{1}`, `\newcoltest{2}`, etc., precisely because

Comment: ... `\newcoltest` doesn't expand inside `\edef`. OTOH, with @Schrödinger'scat's approach and expandable commands inside the replacement text of `\newcoltest`, the dynamically-created cells as stored by `pgfplotstable` contain the *results* of the expandable computations, which allows other “users” of the table data (graphing, etc.) to examine values.

Comment: I omit the `\noexpand` in the @Schrödinger's cat's  code based on what you say and it also works, you're right!

Comment: @4lrdyD Good catch, sorry. I had forgotten @Schrödinger'scat had left the `\noexpand` in place when I wrote the previous comments, but this suggests you understood well what I meant. Bed time, now. :-)